# CommandTimeout Property

Tags: .net, timeout

I'm trying to figure out under which circumstances will a DBCommand\SqlCommand actually timeout.

**The only two I can think off is:**

1. The query\stored Proc takes longer to execute than the time allowed.
2. The server is getting allot of request and a query that should be quick ends up stuck in queue or something while the time runs out and then throws a error.

Is my way of thinking correct and are there scenarios I'm missing?

Also I'm trying to find out if there is a negative to creating a too large amount for the timeout, say either infinite with zero, or like an hour+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), in my experience, it's usually the server's fault though. Bad database design seems to be a primary cause of timeouts for us.

As far as large or infinite timeouts, you risk tying up the SQL server in the processing of your request, but there's nothing that says you can't. 0 is the infinite timeout for SqlCommand.